# How to replace or prepend a character to a list of string in a linq query?

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a string like similar to this `Hello [name] [lastname]`

I then convert it to a `list<string>` by `List<string> = "Hello [name] [lastname]".Split(" ").ToList()"`

Problem with this I need `Hello [name] [lastname]` to be `'Hello' name lastname` and stored in the list as this.

Problem of altering the string is I can't come up with a way I both can remove `[` and `]` and adding single quoutes witout having to go through string multiple times using multiple replaces?

Is it possible to do it with a single command? -  like defining a rule?

Comment: Easy :             string input = "Hello [name] [lastname]";
            string[] output = input.Split(new char[] { '[', ' ', ']' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToArray();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regular expression to identify the words and [tokens] from your string. Then using a match evaluator in a [Regex.Replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace?view=netframework-4.8#System_Text_RegularExpressions_Regex_Replace_System_String_System_String_System_Text_RegularExpressions_MatchEvaluator_), you can apply your custom rule to surround words with single quotes, and for the tokens the Regex capturing group will already have stripped off the surrounding square brackets for us.

For example,

```
var output = Regex
    .Replace("Hello [name] [lastname]", @"\[(?<token>.+?)\]|(?<word>[^\s]+)", (match) =>
    {
        var wordMatch = match.Groups["word"];
        if (wordMatch.Success) return $"'{wordMatch.Value}'";
        return match.Groups["token"].Value;
    })
    .Split(' ')
    .ToList();
```

Will output the following list:

```
[0] 'Hello'
[1] name
[2] lastname
```

Answer (score 0):

If your input string always starts with `Hello`, then a solution will be:

```
List<string> output = new List<string>() { "'Hello'" }.Concat(input.Split(new char[] { '[', ' ', ']' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Skip(1)).ToList();
```

Otherwise, if the first word of your input string is not fixed, then you could do:

```
List<string> output = new List<string>() { $"'{input.Split(' ')[0]}'" }.Concat(input.Split(new char[] { '[', ' ', ']' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Skip(1)).ToList();
```

However, I would recommend splitting this code into multiple lines instead of doing so with a single command like you requested.